# Phalcon installation on ubuntu 12.04 LTS with XAMPP server

Tags: php, linux, xampp, ubuntu-12.04, phalcon

I have a problem in the installation of Phalcon framework on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I followed the instruction listed [in this page](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html#linux-solaris-mac)

It says that you must add the extension in php.ini

and when I made "locate php.ini" in my terminal, 5 directories had been appeared and I put 
the extension which is `"extension=phalcon.so"` in the upper three directories (See the attached picture).

[image]

It doesn't work up till now because when I open `phpinfo()` in the localhost web page, phalcon doesn't appear.

btw I use xampp server

any ideas ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Probably version or configuration difference between your machine's PHP and XAMPP's  PHP

If you are trying to use Phalcon with XAMPP, you might have some compilation issues. When compiling Phalcon, the default code uses your machine's php scripts to run the function **phpize** instead of the XAMPP's php scripts. Then, when you just compile and add the .so to XAMPP, it will try to use an extension built from a different PHP version or configuration. Of course that error only occurs when your Ubuntu PHP version or configuration is different from your XAMPP php version.

So, to correct this add an extra argument on Phalcon compilation as follows:

```
###Part 1###
$git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
$cd cphalcon/build
$sudo ./install --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
```

We added the argument **--with-php-config=** which will say what php configuration should be used. After running the ./install, you should see in your terminal the message **"Thanks for compiling Phalcon!
Build succeed: Please restart your web server to complete the installation"**. If that doesnt happen, it means that the pahlcon.so was not generated correctly. If that happens, open the ./install file and replace all **phpize** occurrence for **phpize --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config**. There are two occurences, one in line 59 and other in line 63. Also replace the **./configure --enable-phalcon** for ./configure --enable-phalcon --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config on line 63. After that run again the command **$ sudo ./install --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config** and check if you see the message **"Thanks for compiling Phalcon!
Build succeed: Please restart your web server to complete the installation"**

After that, continue the process normally:

```
###Part 2###
$vi /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

In the open file press key **":"** then type **"1000"** then press **enter key**. that should take you to the 1000 line of the file, around where the *etension=xxxx.so* are. If not, press down arrow until you find this area. something like this:

```
##Part 3##
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
```

When your cursor is somewhere like that, press **"i"** for insertion mode and add the line:

```
##part 4##
extension=phalcon.so
```

Attention, don't put a **";"** before, that means it is a commented line. After that save the file by pressing **":"** after that press **"x"** then **push enter**. That menas you saved the file.

Then, finally restart your webserver by using the command:

```
##part 5##
$sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

By now, everything is gret to go. Hope it helps!

Comment: In Part #1 it give me "Build Succeed" when I write just sudo ./install not sudo ./install --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config...... But by following the steps 2,3,4 and 5 ..... It finally works !! :) Yesssss, Thanks for your help Hiro, You are great :) :)

Comment: I think the solution to that problem was in the lines you told me to edit in ./install file because I made the steps 2 -> 5 more than one time before and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me after spending some time.

In install file cphalcon/build/install

i've change

```
phpize --clean
```

**To**

```
/opt/lampp/bin/phpize --clean
```

And the last line **From**

```
phpize && ./configure --enable-phalcon && make && make install && echo -e "\nThanks for compiling Phalcon!\nBuild succeed: Please restart your web server to complete the installation"
```

**To**

```
/opt/lampp/bin/phpize && ./configure --enable-phalcon --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config && make && make install && echo -e "\nThanks for compiling Phalcon!\nBuild succeed: Please restart your web server to complete the installation"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct php.ini for XAMPP on Ubuntu is located at `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`.
2. There you have to add this line: `extension=phalcon.so`.
3. Make sure you have your compiled .so file in the folder for PHP extensions of XAMPP: `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions`.
4. Then you have to restart your web server. I think you forgot this step.

Comment: I think I have missed step three, in folder extensions I have some files named: oci8.so, opcache.so, pgsql.so, radius.so, xdebug.so,,,,,and I don't have phalcon.so in that folder

Comment: what should I do to have the .so file in the directory you have mentioned in step three.

Comment: copy the file to the directory.

Comment: What says phpinfo(), do you have PHP 5.3, 5.4 or 5.5 installed? Is there still no entry of phalcon? Maybe you have not correctly compiled phalcon.so, try for Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install git-core gcc autoconf` and `sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-mysql`. Then `git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git`, `cd cphalcon/build` and `sudo ./install`. After these steps you should have a correctly compiled phalcon.so extension file inside the cphalcon folder.